# InApp Billing - Unable to get purchase token on different device getting you already own this item error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, token, in-app-billing

I am integrating InApp Biiling in my android application, Once I make purchase on one device then unable to get the purchase token on another device. It is not premium or subscription.

Comment: Are you logged in using the same account on both devices?

Comment: yes, the account on both devices is same.